# How to count price of each item looking to number of items?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, count

I have XML request which returns table of menu like shown in 1st table. Here is my code snippet:

```
HTML

<body>
    <h1>Food Menu</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="simpleXML()">Show the Menu</button>
    <br><br>
    <table id="menu-table"></table>
    <br>
    <div id="btn2"></div>
    <br>
    <table id="menu-count-table"></table>
    <br><br>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

JS

    function simpleXML() {
  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      menu(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function menu(xml) {
  let i;
  let xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  let menuTable="<tr><th>name</th><th>price</th><th>description</th><th>calories</th></tr>";
  let x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("food");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    menuTable += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("calories")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("menu-table").innerHTML = menuTable;

  const btn = document.createElement("button"); 
  btn.innerHTML = "Make an order";
  document.getElementById("btn2").appendChild(btn);

  btn.onclick = function(){
    simpleXML2();
  };
}
```

My code returns xml doc like in 1st table in the photo and after clicking make an order it returns second table but without count and summary. How to add count summary rows?

Comment: Hi ,how does second table is generated ? can you add html code for that as well ?

Comment: I will update. For now I just put instead of count and summary just text. I am trying to make practice from w3schools

Comment: I updated code snippet

Comment: Also ,`summary` is `price * count` ?

Comment: yes, summary is price * count. I do not know how to add count to increment number of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all trs to get the total of `count` and `summary` columns.First when you append `trs` to `#menu-count-table` you need to `addEventListener` to all input  put this part of code inside `menu` function as well your `count` column should be `<input type="number">` change that as well.

Now , whenever `count` input gets change `calculate` function will get called .There as you can see in below code i have loop through `trs` using `for-loop` and have done calculation by getting values from `tds` and finally added final result inside `spans` tag.

***Demo Code*** (with dummy datas):

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-count-table tr");
calculate();
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-count-table input")
//add event listerner to all inputs
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('change', calculate);
}

function calculate() {
  var count = 0;
  var summary = 0;
  //loop through tr not from 1 because 1st row is ths..and not last as well
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    var items = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td"); //get all tds
    if (items.length === 0) continue;
    sum = parseFloat(items[1].innerHTML * items[4].children[0].value) //count and price mutlipy them
    items[5].innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2); //add new sum to summary column td
    count = count + parseInt(items[4].children[0].value) //add total for both count and summary 
    summary = summary + parseFloat(items[5].innerHTML)

  }
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count; //put result
  document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = summary.toFixed(2);


}
```

```html
<table id="menu-count-table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>calories</th>
    <th>count</th>
    <th>summary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>5.5</td>
    <td>abcd..</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <!--for taking count-->
    <td><input class="count" min="1" type="number" value="3"></td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>5.4</td>
    <td>acebcd..</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td><input class="count" min="1" type="number" value="3"></td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>6.2</td>
    <td>abcfrfrd..</td>
    <td>540</td>
    <td><input class="count" min="1" type="number" value="3"></td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>3.8</td>
    <td>abcd..</td>
    <td>503</td>
    <td><input class="count" min="1" type="number" value="3"></td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td>Count : <span id="count"></span></td>
    <td>Summary : <span id="summary"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```